# How to open the serial device exclusively in pyserial?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyserial

I want to open the serial device exclusively by pyserial in ubuntu 20.04. I tried the following two approaches.

1. To use the exclusive flag in pyserial.

```
ser = Serial(port=serialdevice, baudrate=115200, bytesize=8, timeout=2, exclusive=True)
```

2. To use fcntl as below.

```
        try:
            ser = Serial(port=serialdevice, baudrate=115200, bytesize=8, timeout=2)
            if ser.isOpen():
                try:
                    fcntl.flock(ser.fileno(), fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)

        except Exception a e:
                    print(e)
```

Both approaches do not work. There is no any lock file generated under /var/lock.

Finally, I can only created the lock file manually under /var/lock as below.

```
   try:
        device_name = serialdevice.split("/")[2]

        lock_file_name = "/var/lock/LCK.."+device_name
        ser = Serial(port=serialdevice, baudrate=115200, bytesize=8, timeout=2)
        if ser.isOpen():
            open(lock_file_name, 'w').write(str(os.getpid()))
        else:
            print("port not open")

    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed to open serial port exclusively. Pls check if the serial port is already used by other tools")
        print(e)
        return
```

May I ask what could be wrong in the first two approaches? Is the manual method used generally in opening the serial port exclusively? Do I need to delete the lock file manually when the python script quit?

Thanks!

Comment: `exclusive=True` works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

> 1. To use the exclusive flag in pyserial.

Creating Serial object with `exclusive=True` will cause pyserial to internally use flock to lock the serial device as we can see in the source code for [serialposix.py](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/7aeea35429d15f3eefed10bbb659674638903e3a/serial/serialposix.py#L392).

> 2. To use fcntl as below.

This is essential the same as the first method.

> There is no any lock file generated under /var/lock.

The method above locks the serial character device file, so you won't see the file generated under /var/lock because the lock file is actually the `/dev/ttyXXX` file itself.

Your final approach will not work and you only create a file named `"/var/lock/LCK.."+device_name` but there is no locking that happens. If you want to use your final approach to use a separate lock file, you still need to flock the `"/var/lock/LCK.."+device_name` file yourself. Example:

```
try:
    device_name = serialdevice.split("/")[2]

    lock_file_name = "/var/lock/LCK.."+device_name
    ser = Serial(port=serialdevice, baudrate=115200, bytesize=8, timeout=2)
    if ser.isOpen():
        lock_file = open(lock_file_name, 'w')
        fcntl.flock(lock_file, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
        lock_file.write(str(os.getpid()))
    else:
        print("port not open")

except Exception as e:
    print("Failed to open serial port exclusively. Pls check if the serial port is already used by other tools")
    print(e)
    return
```

You don't really need to delete the file since it barely take up any space but it is nice to clean up.